# Laravel Error Server Error after uploading File - Permission Server html_public

Tags: laravel

I can upload correctly my files in my Localhost inside `/public`. But in my server i got Error Server. Maybe i need to change somes permissions or set storage path. I tried all my best but i dn't know much about permissions. Can some one help me to resolve that please ?

[image: Error]
This is my controller code :

```
public function addPerson(Request $request)
{
    $person = new Person;
    $exploded = explode(',', $request->image);
    $decoded = base64_decode($exploded[1]);

    if (str_contains($exploded[0], 'jpeg')) {
        $extension="jpg";
    } else {
        $extension="png";
    }

    $fileName = str_random().'.'.$extension;
    $path = public_path().'/'.$fileName;

    file_put_contents($path, $decoded);
    $person->photo = $fileName;

    $person->save();
    return back()->with('success', 'New Position added successfully.');
}
```

Since i uploaded my Project in Cpanel, i didn't change something.  Thank you.

update :
I activate app_debug , and got this problem instead 
[image]

Comment: First thing you can do to debug it is to set code in try catch block and check response. Something like [this](https://pastebin.com/HUiz0iuh).

Comment: Can't understand sir !

Comment: I edited to be full method now. Check posted link again. Delete you method code and put what I linked. That way you will know what exact server error is in matter. You can study more detailed about exceptions ( and try catch blocks) [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

Comment: I got my error, please check my update post. But still don't know how to fix it

Comment: Ok, this is better now. You have to set ownership and permission over directory where you want to upload image. Follow these instructions of [how to set permission for upload directory](https://superuser.com/questions/581194/setting-correct-permissions-for-uploading-files), first read that answer and do how it says (it worths for Linux; if you are using Windows than right click on directory and Set Permission or google for "how to set directory permission on Windows").